# Header Filename as variable

Tags: php

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-disposition: attachment;filename="'.$this->fileName.'"');
```

Apparently the second line is giving me an error

> Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected in **/storage/ssd1/433/12154433/public_html/FileNa.** on line **84**

And I don't know why... Whenever I manually enter the file name it is fine, however, whenever I enter the file name as a variable it throws this error.

Comment: What does `var_dump($this->fileName);` give you?

Comment: It returns string(2241) " Test name @vivek_23

Comment: So it returns `Test name` ? What is the extension of the file name? `.csv`?

Comment: string(2241) is too much for a filename. Are you sure it is not the content of the file?

Comment: Yes, and it is a .csv

Comment: @MarkusZeller It is, I don't know why this is happening. White spaces?

Comment: Please do a `var_dump($this->fileName)`.

Comment: @MarkusZeller string(2241) " Test name

Comment: This is impossible. 2241 byte are **WAY MORE** than "Test name". I would expect something like string(8) "test.csv"

Comment: I would expect so too... I'm trying to figure out why

Comment: Check/provide the code where `$this->filename` is set.

Comment: It turns out there was something wrong with my string for some weird reason and was able to figure it out. Thank you.

Comment: I dont think you are doing right what is been said in comments and answers.

Answer (score -1):

- Make sure you are having php opening tag as very first character.
- When any char is given out before any header, it will fail.
- Also be sure to exit();

```php
<?php

// Your class things

header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$this->fileName.'"');

// Your output things

exit();
```

> - Capital D of Disposition
> - Space after semicolon after attachment

As seen in the comments, the filename is a string(2241) which **must** be wrong. Use a shorter one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried this and still no luck

Answer (score -1):

Change with double quote like that:

```
<?php

// Your class things

header("Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$this->fileName");

// Your output things

exit();
```

Be sure `$this->fileName` is name of the file and not content